# Vue Component to Nuxt Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm having hard time converting this sample in Vue to Nuxt.
[LINK](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/svg.html)
I wanted to use the vue polygon in my nuxt application.

can anywone help me with my problem? Or any good plugin to use in nuxt.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share code of what you already tried?